# Move ReactJS, NextJS config files in a "config" directory rather than the root folder

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, config, project-structure

I have some config files in the root folder of the app such as:

- tailwind.config.js
- postcss.config.js
- next.config.js
  -.babelrc
- tsconfig.json

and so on

Is there any way to move this files in a directory called "config" and the app still works ?

Comment: Why you need that?

Comment: Just to clean the project directory structure